# Android bus tracking application to track location and update location onto map

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I've been trying to create a bus tracking application but I'm stuck at getting the app shows the location of the phone periodically. My objective is to get the phone be located and plot onto the map. I've been trying to get a marker to show my current location and updates it every second (I use phone to track the bus)

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {
private final String TAG = "ThisIsStressful";

private TextView mLocationView;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mLocationView = new TextView(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {


    //enable location of user
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    //map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mapCenter, 163));


    // One example of Bus stop (Hard coded bus stop)
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
            .position(new LatLng(2.975177, 101.729509))
            .title("Murni")
            .snippet("Bus Stop")
            .flat(true));
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Connect the client.
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000); // Update location every second

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has failed");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLocationView.setText("Location received: " + location.toString());
}
```

As you can see in the location changed method. I can show in terms of string. But I don't know how to show it onto the map as a marker.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code in your onLocationChanged method.

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
           .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
           .title("My Location")
           .snippet("Current Location")
           .flat(true));
```

Comment: It crashed. I even put "protected GoogleMap map;" at the top. Next thing i tried is to change the "new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())" as a hardcoded number. Still it crashed. turned off the "map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);" still the same. I get NullPointerException error at the onLocationChanged method.